# Running parallel terraform apply commands on Terraform Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

We are using Terraform cloud and have multiple workspaces that are completely different GCP projects. When we apply changes in these different environments at the same time Terraform Cloud queues these runs one after other. However these projects are completely separate, and they shouldn't block each other. Is there any way to run these jobs in parallel?

Comment: You run a Terraform plan/apply for each workspace ?

Comment: yes I am running separate "terraform apply" commands from ci/cd

Comment: You can't run a parallel job per Terraform command ? Your CI CD is done with Gitlab CI ?

Comment: yes even if I do that, the next run is locked on the terrraform cloud side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free tier of Terraform Cloud, at the time of writing, limits each organization to only one active run at a time.

Higher paid tiers can have higher limits for run concurrency, which would then allow multiple workspaces to have active runs at the same time.

There is no way to apply concurrently across two workspaces for a free tier organization.

Comment: yup that's what i figured! Not super transparent from their documentation, as I was in a trial run and this was still not available